# Using for loop and charAt to check if each letter appears exactly twice in a word

Tags: java

i'm writing a program in java that checks if a letter appers exactly twice, i was able to write it but my problem is that for some words the code doesn't check if the letter appear exactly twice.
here is my code:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  isDoubloon("abba");
  isDoubloon("Shanghaiingss");/*it still prints out true though 's' does appear exactly twice*/}


//checks if every letter appears twice in a word
public static void isDoubloon(String s){
    String l=s.toLowerCase();
    int count=0;

    for(int i= 0; i<l.length()-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<l.length();j++){

            if(l.charAt(i)==l.charAt(j)) count++;
        }

    }
    if(count%2==0){
        System.out.println("True, This is a doubloon");
    }else
        System.err.println("False, This is not a doubloon");


}}
```

Comment: Set count to a boolean. Simply set it to true and if it is already true set it back to false and exit the loop

Comment: Well you do have count%2==0 which means there was an even number of times the letter showed up.. if you want exactly two just do count == 2

Comment: You are counting the total number of paired letters in your string and seeing if it's even. This is not what you say you are trying to do. For instance, the strings `aa` and `abcabc` would both fail your test.

Comment: You could use a `hashmap` to store each letter and the number of times it occurs in the `string`. Loop through your `hashmap`'s values and if any of them do not equal 2 then it is not a `doubloon`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole logic is not correct. You have to check for every letter in your text if it occurs twice.

Try this:

```
String l=s.toLowerCase();
boolean check = true;

for(int i= 0; i<l.length();i++){
    int count=0;
    for(int j=0;j<l.length();j++){
        if(l.charAt(i)==l.charAt(j)) count++;
     }
     if (count != 2) {
         check = false;
         break;
     }
}
if(check==true){
    System.out.println("True, This is a doubloon");
}else
    System.out.println("False, This is not a doubloon");
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, your's works perfectly, but was my error initializing j=i+1; and count%2==0;...i'm kinda new to java so its pretty tough

Comment: @JO_VIC The main problem was that you haven't checked each character by its own (counter outside the loop). And the `%2` operator doesn't make much sense, because it is also true if the occurence is 4,6,8,... But keep on programming. Your code style looks good. It was just a logical mistake :)

Comment: @Blobanat, oww i get the flaw now hmm good ,the encouragement is gon make me work harder :)  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code counts how often each letter occurs (-1) and adds all this values. If the result is even you imply that each letter is exactly twice in the word. That cannot work.

Simply try the word "aaabbbb". (your code think it is a doubloon)

So you need to check if no character occurs exactly twice and that for each character separately.

You could do it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if(isDoubloon("Shanghaiingss")){
    System.out.println("True, This is a doubloon");
  }else{
    System.err.println("False, This is not a doubloon");
  }
}   


public static boolean isDoubloon(final String s) {
    final String l = s.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < l.length(); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < l.length(); j++) {
           if (l.charAt(i) == l.charAt(j)) {
              count++;
              if (2 < count) {
                return false; // more than twice
              } 
           }
        }
        if (1 == count) {
            return false; // character occurs only once
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This algorithm is similar to yours. But it is far from fast **O(n²)**. Is you need it you can implement it faster **O(n)** but you would need some extra space.

Comment: @JO_VIC It is like the efficiency of the algorithm. See here: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 0):

The main flaw here is that you are using a single "count" variable when you want to do a count for each letter.

I would suggest using a map to hold a count for each letter, loop over the list and add each letter to your map and finally iterate over the map and confirm all values are 2.

```
public static void isDoubloon(String s){
    String l=s.toLowerCase();
    Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap();

    for(int i= 0; i<l.length()-1;i++){
        int prevValue = counts.getOrDefault(l.charAt(i), 0);
        counts.put(l.charAt(i), prevValue + 1);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry: counts.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() != 2) {
            System.err.println("False, This is not a doubloon");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("True, This is a doubloon");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution

```
private boolean isDoubloon(String s) {
    String convertWord = s.toLowerCase();
    char[] letter = convertWord.toCharArray();
    int[] count = new int[26];
    for (int letters = 0; letters < letter.length; letters++) {
        char index = letter[letters];
        count[index - 97]++;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < 26; i++ ) {
        if (count[i] != 0 && count[i] != 2) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isDoubloon(String s) {
    if (s.length() %2 != 0)
        return false;

    String str = s.toLowerCase();

    while (str.length() > 0) {
        int index2 = str.indexOf(str.charAt(0), 1);
        if (index2 == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        int index3 = str.indexOf(str.charAt(0), index2 + 1);
        if (index3 != -1) {
            return false;
        }

        str = str.substring(1, index2) + str.substring(index2 + 1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not happy with any of the above variants. I'm not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory Java Streams examples:

#### groupingBy() and counting()

```
public static boolean isDoubloon(String str) {
    return
        // Stream over chars, and box to Integer
        // These will be the ASCII values of the chars
        !str.chars().boxed() 

        // Group by identity
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
        // and map each key to the count of characters
            Collectors.counting()))

        // We now have a Map<Integer, Long>, the Integer being the character
        // value and the Long being the number of occurrences.
        // Stream over the Map's values
        .values().stream()

        // Retain all values unequal to 2
        .filter(i -> !Objects.equals(i, 2L))

        // Shortcut if found and check if a value is present
        .findAny().isPresent();

        // If a value is present, that means that there are one or more
        // characters with less or more than two occurrences.
}
```

<sub>https://ideone.com/PT8sQi</sub>

#### distinct() and count()

```
public static boolean isDoubloon(String str) {
    long distinct = str.chars().distinct().count();
    long length = str.length();

    return (length % 2 == 0 && length / 2 == distinct);
}
```

<sub>https://ideone.com/UaOKDF</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
//Using for loop and charAt to check if each letter appears exactly twice in a word
//This program takes an input
//validates the input to be sure its a string
//checks if the input has a letter appeariing twice in it (doubloon)
//Tells you if its a doubloon or not`enter code here`enter code here`
//YOU CAN TAKE OUT THE VALIDATION TO MAKE IT WORK WITH STRING OF N`enter code here`UBERS
//My first push to stackoverflow Dec 5,2023 . Took me 2 days to get this.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Doubloon{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        isDoubloon();
    }

    public static void isDoubloon(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput ;
        int i;
        int x;
        boolean isNotDoolean = false;


        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");

//Validate user input
        do{
            if(input.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Numbers are not allowed");
                System.out.println("Try again: ");
                input.nextLine();
                continue;
            }else if(!input.hasNextInt()){
//userInput = input.nextLine();
                break;
            }
        }while(input.hasNextInt());

//store validated input
        userInput = input.nextLine();

//parse userinput and confirm if it is a doubloon or not
        for(x = 0; x < userInput.length(); x++){
            for( i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i ++){
                if(userInput.charAt(x) == userInput.charAt(i) && x != i){
                    System.out.print("Yes! this is a doubloon");
                    return;
                }else{isNotDoolean = true;}
                if(x == userInput.length()-1 && isNotDoolean == true){
                    System.out.print("Oh no! this is not a doubloon");
                    return;
                }

            }

        } //end of for loop;


    }
}
```

Comment: Look no further. I had to practically lay items on a table to come up with this solution. The GitHub link is https://github.com/Akaiso/JRefresh/blob/main/Doubloon.java